# ¿Por que no se puede agradecer en los comentarios?

Tags: discusión

Pues eso, ¿Por que no se puede agradecer en los comentarios?

Entiendo la parte de no poner el +1 que para eso esta la flecha hacia arriba de votar como útil la respuesta o pregunta pero... ¿Qué tiene de malo agradecer por una respuesta que nos sirve?

Yo pienso que agradecer nos conecta como humanos, contribuye al optimismo, confianza y seguridad a la persona que le agradecemos, mejora nuestras relaciones haciéndolas más sanas y por ende, más satisfactorias. En conclusión, nos enfoca al positivismo y a los valores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que no es un foro pero supongo que poder agradecer... No está de más.

Comment: Normalmente los comentarios contienen información adicional a la pregunta/respuesta por lo que se intenta reducir el "ruido" que se pueda generar con comentarios que no contribuyen ni a responder ni a clarificar nada.

Comment: @MiquelColl te recomiendo convertir ese comentario en respuesta.

Comment: La ironía de ver que esta pregunta no tiene respuesta aceptada no se escapa!

Answer (score 2):

La manera en que agradecemos aquí es por votar a favor de los comentarios, respuestas or preguntas.  En vez de crear "ruido" por la comunidad, los votos a favor favorecen a los usuarios que lo reciben y es una indicación clara y funcional de que lo escrito fue de ayuda para alguien.

La mejor manera de agradecer a alguien que responda a nuestra pregunta es el de seleccionar esa respuesta como la aceptada.

Comment: Deberían poner un botón de leído o visto, de manera que si no te resultó útil el comentario, pero te gustaría avisarle al usuario que comentó que viste su comentario, para que al menos sepa que debe eliminarlo. Además cuando reportas un comentario a los moderadores, debería enviarle un mensaje en la bandeja de entrada al usuario que comentó para que elimine su comentario.

Answer (score 2):

Normalmente los comentarios contienen información adicional a la pregunta/respuesta por lo que se intenta reducir el "ruido" que se pueda generar con comentarios que no contribuyen ni a responder ni a clarificar nada.

Para *agradecer* la respuesta de alguien que te ha ayudado ya existen maneras de hacerlo sin añadir comentarios:

- **Marcando respuesta aceptada** si es la mejor para la pregunta planteada (si se es el autor de la pregunta).
- **Votando a favor** de la respuesta.

Personalmente dejo bastantes comentarios pero siempre intento aportar algún detalle más o pedir clarificación sobre algo (seguramente ya te has dado cuenta con mis contribuciones hasta la fecha, tengo tantos comentarios como respuestas (¡o más!)).